# DIV Exibir texto ao passar o mouse

Tags: javascript, css, html5

como eu faço pra aparecer uma palavra dentro de uma DIV ao passar o mouse sobre ela?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Ativar HOVER sem clicar na mesma div](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88636/ativar-hover-sem-clicar-na-mesma-div)

Comment: Já possui algum código? O que fez até agora?

Comment: Você consegue fazer isso somente com CSS, utilizando a propriedade display em conjunto com :hover

Comment: Oi Christian, bem-vindo ao site. Aqui não deletamos as perguntas depois de resolvidas. A ideia é que os conteúdos aqui possam ajudar a mais gente além de quem perguntou.

Comment: Se alguma das respostas abaixo resolveu seu problema, por favor marque o "tick" verde ao lado dela

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o evento [onmouseover();](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp) do javascript para fazer o texto aparecer, e, se quiser, utilizar o [onmouseout();](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_mouseout.asp) para fazer o texto desaparecer após o mouse sair da div, observe:

É notável discutir que em celulares esses eventos terão o funcionamento de 'click', ou seja, só irão ser ativados se o usuário tocar na div ou fora dela.

```js
function aparecerTexto() {
  document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "Texto";
}
function reset() {
  document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "";
}
```

```css
#div{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#f00;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
    
  <body>
    <div onmouseover="aparecerTexto();" onmouseout="reset();" id="div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Eu fiz utilizando jQuery

css:

```
.corpo {
  width:200px;
  min-height:50px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

html :

```
<div class="corpo" id="seuId" onmouseover="$('#seuId').html('seuTexto');" onmouseleave="$('#seuId').html('')"></div>
```

O evento `onmouseover` é para quando o mouse estiver em cima da div adicionar o texto que você deseja, e o evento `onmouseleave` é acionado quando você tira o mouse de cima da div assim removendo o texto antes inserido

Comment: Considere não utilizar jQuery para uma situação tão simples que pode ser resolvida com javascript puro. Tente explicar ou adicionar sites que explicam o que você está utilizando para resolver o problema.

Comment: @WesleyNascimento se no projeto ja tiver jQuery se torna mais valido, pois a redução em linhas de codigo é notavel

Comment: "se no projeto já tiver jQuery"

Comment: Much jQuery!!!!